# PHP include in Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015

Tags: php, html, include

Recently I've been trying to do php includes for my html page.

I made the php file in Dreamweaver which looks like this

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

filename: nav.php

Then I tried to include it inside my main html page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav"><?php include("nav.php");?></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

filename: index.html

I also want to use css to style my php include, how do I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't your main HTML file is php?

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver so the php structure looks like html.

Comment: when you create a php file in Dreamweaver there will be some html code present on creation. There is no need to keep it there if you don't need it. Add the filenames to your question so it is more obvious what you are doing

Comment: No matter which php editor you are using, you are following right way to include your file. Also whatever style you will be adding in your main file, will reflect in your included file.

Comment: @TimothySusanto can you please share the full name of your both files.

Comment: Your include will only work if your file that contains this include command is named something like 'myphpfile.php'. It must end with .php

Comment: @RST I did end it with php, with the filename nav.php

Comment: As stated in the answer, that is where you go wrong. I said 'the file that contains the include command'. You named that one `index.html`. This means it will be treated like html, all of it. Rename it 'index.php' and you will be fine.

Comment: @RST Ok I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps/structure you should follow.

1) Your file which needs to be included which you have given a name "nav.php" which is correct.

2) Your main file should also be php file. For eg. it's name should be something like "MyMain.php"

3) As you want to apply css. You can include external css in your main file (here i.e MyMain.php). Or else you can also write css in the same file (MyMain.php) in `<style></style>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

To load or "include" CSS you can add this in your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Comment: He is trying to add a menu, not a CSS file

Comment: Quote : "I also want to use css to style my php include..."

Comment: Fair enough. I missed the 2nd question. One question per topic works better. Unfortunately the system will not permit me to upvote unless you make a change to the answer :(